# How to send request from PHP App Engine to GCM

Tags: android, google-app-engine, server, gcloud

I am using PHP to build a App Engine application, but when I try to connect to the GCM server, it is returning the below error:
**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$data' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ')' Line 6**
I'm using this code...

```
    $gcm_regid = "kjfadlfk;dkf;fpoekfldfk;";
    $url = "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send";

    $data = ['data' => 'this', 'registration_ids' => $gcm_regid];

    $data = http_build_query($data);
    $context = [
      'https' => [
        'method' => 'POST',
        'header' => "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" .
                    "Authorization: key=" . GOOGLE_API_KEY . "\r\n",
        'content' => $data
      ]
    ];
    $context = stream_context_create($context);
    $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

Comment: That is not all. It will mention a line number too. So then you know which statement is causing the error. And then you should tell us.

Comment: It mentioned a line number 6 according to this code $data = http_build_query($data);

Comment: And... Please comment on that! You first. Then we.

Comment: I've checked the above code in App Engine and it works flawlessly. Which PHP version are you using? Are you modifying those variables meanwhile?